# Improper integrals over the reals and surreal numbers

Tags: analysis, logic, field-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

Is it possible to assign improper integrals over the reals a surreal value in a consistent way? Are there any papers available on this?

Note that I am not inquiring about formalizing integration over the surreal themselves, which I realize is still a somewhat open problem. Rather, I would like to identify an integral with a number $z$ in the surreals, e.g.

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} x^2 dx = z, \; z\in \text{Surreals}$

with the ultimate purpose of comparing and performing algebra on the values of "classically" divergent integrals.

Comment: For integrals such as those, the partial integrals $\int \limits_{u=0}^x f(u)du$ are defined and are amenable to many computations, so they (or their germs at infinity) could serve as proxies for the divergent integral. 
For those whose primitive are transseries (e.g. $\frac{1}{3} x^3$ here), you may identify them with their "value at $\omega$", i.e. their value under the natural embedding of log-exp transseries into the field of surreal numbers (see *Transseries as germs of surreal functions* of Berarducci and Mantova). I don't know if that is useful or interesting in any sense though...

Comment: That paper is very useful, thank you! I'm interested in computing moments of statistical distributions that have either undefined moments or are non-analytic so may only be approached via perturbation theory-- in general I won't be able to solve the partial integral. I'm hoping I can work out a result using surreal analysis :)

Comment: Then this paper might not help you a lot since transseries and their extensions are specific functions, excluding for instance any kind of oscillatory behavior, and not containing various usual functions. I don't know if there is such a thing as "surreal analysis" at this point, but there are works on defining integrals of functions on surreal numbers: in particular the thesis of Antongiulio Fornasiero and the article *Integration on the Surreals: a Conjecture of Conway, Kruskal and Norton* by O. Costin, P. Ehrlich, and H.M. Friedman.

Comment: Oh wow, this is really great. Their examples hit on exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Do you work within surreal numbers? Is it a particularly active field? I'm really looking forward to surreal analysis getting filled out. IMO results from this field look exceptionally promising. It seems like the standard extension of the reals for the purpose of calculus and analysis miss 99% of the story, similar to the way that throwing out factors of sqrt(-1) prior to the 1800s missed the opportunity to develop an internally consistent, powerful algebraic field with consequences for all of mathematics and physics

Comment: I am an undergraduate, and I am working on surreal numbers yes. I am specifically working on an aspect of surreal numbers depicted in the article *Numbers, germs and transseries* of Aschenbrenner, vdDries and vdHoeven, so this is not related to real analysis. I would say surreal number seem to be a relatively active field, given that it is narrow (the study of an object) but can still be studied in various angles, and there have been many recent publications related to surreal numbers. (to continue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81641/discussion-between-nombre-and-kapaw).